# why site continously redirected although I have removed the .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am working on a site which is installed on

home/myuser/mywebsite

in this folder there are two further folders one is `members` and other is `wordpress`

My site is accessed in a way like this

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/members/
```

`wordpress folder` contains few pages which are used only for regersitered members, so if I access a page from wordpress folder, url becomes..

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/protected/?pageID
```

now the issue is, I cant login it `wordpress folder` if I use

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/wordpress/wp-admin/
```

I am redirected to

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/members/wp-login?redirected_to......
```

I am messing with it for two days, but cant figure out what is happening here

can somebody GUIDE me please

Comment: You can be redirected via PHP as well, you probably need to update your settings for the install location.

Comment: can you suggest me the changed I need to do?

Comment: Open your mysql database in phpmyadmin, go to the config table, and modify the install location setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked

- siteurl
- home

options under **wp_options** table. 
They must have value `http://www.mywebsite.com/wordpress` in your case.